# Cassandra data modelling to retrieve data by datetime range

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have a requirement to log when a service is accessed by user to get some data. I am using Cassandra to log who accessed and what time it was accessed and whether the response is success or not.  Then a report should display all the information based on datetime range. I am creating the table as below

```
CREATE TABLE accesslog (
 id bigint,
 location text,
 accesstype text,
 requesterid text,
 accesseddate date,
 accesseddatetime time,
 PRIMARY KEY ((id,accesseddate), accesseddatetime)
 ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (accesseddatetime DESC);
```

I am unable to retrieve data based on time range. I am not sure if this data model support querying on datetime. can someone please direct me how to model the table for this so that i can write query to get by date between start-date and end-date

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: Hi Emre.. I  created the table like this and my query is below CREATE TABLE accesslog (
 location text,
 accesstype text,
 requesterid text,
 year int,
 month int,
 accessedtime timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY ((year,month), accessedtime))
 with clustering order by(accessedtime desc);  and my query is  select * from unlockaccesslog
 where  year in (2018,2019) and month in (1,12)
 and  accessedtime > '2018-11-01 06:00:00' and accessedtime <= '2018-12-01 08:00:00';